# Get list of markers within bounds of mapbox map

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, markers

I am trying to get all the markers within the bounds of the map. When the user interacts with the map (zoom in/out, move, click), I want to get all the markers within the bounds of the map to show a list of those markers.

I tried implementing some of the functions this example had without any luck: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-features-within-map-view/

Here is a working version of the map on codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPGgWq

I looked thru what it returned in features and bounds and none of that information helps me accomplish this. I am using the markers so I can display a custom marker image and also set the description that appears in a pop box.

```
map.on('moveend', function (e) {
    var features =  map.queryRenderedFeatures();
    var bounds = map.getBounds();

    console.log(features);
    console.log(bounds);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1)  Mapbox gl js `don't store references for markers` - https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5821#issuecomment-356704579

2) If the marker is added to the map and not saved, then its only representation is the html element inside the map container.

3) So you can use `getBoundingClientRect` to determine if the marker is visible in the map container:

```
function intersectRect(r1, r2) {
  return !(r2.left > r1.right ||
    r2.right < r1.left ||
    r2.top > r1.bottom ||
    r2.bottom < r1.top);
}

function getVisibleMarkers() {
  var cc = map.getContainer();
  var els = cc.getElementsByClassName('marker');
  var ccRect = cc.getBoundingClientRect();
  var visibles = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    var el = els.item(i);
    var elRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    intersectRect(ccRect, elRect) && visibles.push(el);
  }
  if (visibles.length > 0) console.log(visibles);
}
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/rkqdz5g2/ ]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand mapbox gl js API you **cannot** query markers. What I would do is have a list of markers in some kind of data structure and query using [turf.js pointsWithinPolygon](http://turfjs.org/docs#pointsWithinPolygon) function. Where first input would be your markers and second your current viewport.

Comment: I believe it's possible as the markers are features, I am not setting them as layers w/ an id to reference when adding them. I am using the example where it loops thru each piece of geojson and creates them that way. Trying to use a custom marker and have my cake too.